# MySQL access from Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

I want to access MySQL database within my MapReduce program. I have a DBConnection class and I getConnection within the mapper class.The db.properties file is in place and with correct path mentioned in the DBConnection class.
Everytime I run the hadoop jar command I get error  java.io.FileNotFoundException: db.properties (No such file or directory).
How can I resolve this? 
Establishing DB connection in mapper:

```
Connection con  = DBConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String selectRows = "Select count(*) from sample";
```

Thanks

Comment: How we can help you in finding your `db.properties`?

Comment: Hi Arpit..I have my db.properties in place and also have given the correct path in the program.Still getting this error.

Comment: Can you show, where your code is which is calling the `db.properties`?

Comment: public static Connection getConnection() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("/db.properties");
            props.load(fis);

Comment: It's a webapp? If yes, where it is placed in?

Comment: The file is in my java project folder../workspace/projectname/db.properties

Comment: Can you try accessing the same with below code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

**Prior Java 1.7:**

```
InputStream input = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
            try {
                prop.load(input);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
             }finally{
                input.close();
               }
```

**Java 1.7 and ahead:**

```
 try (InputStream input = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties")) {
                prop.load(input);
            } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```